# Suggestions for a Free C++11 IDE

Tags: c++, c++11

I am starting to refresh my C++ skills. I am interested in a good  IDE that supports C++11 and one that is free. I am used to Visual Studio, but I want one that is free and has good support for C++11. I am expecting the IDE to have good intellisense and debugging features. Any suggestions? I have some experience in using Eclipse CDT, but I am not sure of its C++11 support.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop is free and has limited support for C++11 since the 2012 version.

Quoting from the [Website](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express):

> You can use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop to build powerful desktop apps in C#, Visual Basic, and C++.

The list of available C++11 features can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: are you sure? I think C++ is not part of the express edition, is it?

Comment: C++11 support with Visual Studio 2012 is not complete. With the November CTP of the compiler they are claiming to give better support, but the CTP is not integrated with Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.  Check the link below. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: You are right, I found a list of currently supported C++11 features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SudeshSawant : Currently _no_ compiler has complete C++11 support, and in any case you asked for an IDE, not a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT has some C++11 support, for setting it up, see http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/282618/787571/

Apart from it, your choices can also be:

- Qt Creator (can be used for non-Qt project although it is tailored for those)
- KDevelop (has really awesome understanding of C++, and they support most used C++11 features, see http://kdevelop.org/kdevelop/kdevelop-430-final-released-basic-c11-support)

The good thing about these is the support for gcc and clang which have the most complete C++11 support.

If you are on Windows, you can also use Visual Studio with the November CTP, but mind that although the compiler has some new features, the standard library is not updated to use them.